# Preposition "spezialisieren"

Tags: verb, preposition

Which preposition is the right one and what are the differences in the usage of the following prepositions?

For example: Sich spezialisieren in, auf oder für?

Beispiel: "Diese Organisation hat sich ... Quanten-Forschung spezialisiert".

Answer (score 6):

**1) auf**

The most common usage. Would most likely be used in your example sentence

> Diese Organisation hat sich auf Quanten-Forschung spezialisiert

Simply tells us *what* you specialize in.

**2) in**

You might come across this, too. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/spezialisieren) gives an example

> Deshalb sei es heutzutage besonders wichtig, dass Sie den Arbeitsmarkt genau beobachten und sich rechtzeitig in gefragten Bereichen *spezialisieren*, um notwendige Kompetenzen zu erlangen.

Can have the same meaning as *auf*. But it may also look like you narrow down the subject area and tell us that you specialize in some specific part of it. For example, to specialize in law, without specifying the legal subject, like property law.

**3) für**

This would convey a completely different meaning, for example

> Sie spezialisiert sich für ihre neue Aufgabe.

In this case, *für* would not point to something you specialize in, but someone/something you do this for (i. e. *ihre neue Aufgabe*). It doesn't tell us what they specialize in, though.

Comment: Since the English equivalent is "specialize *in*", you can probably expect 2) to become slowly more common like so many other anglicisms.

Answer (score 2):

For a specific topic you only use *Spezialisieren* with *auf*. The object must be in accusative.

> Diese Organisation hat sich *auf* Quanten-Forschung spezialisiert

But The Awful Language is right with 2), you can use *in* when you are discribing the field in which you specialize on a few topics instead of trying to be good in the whole field. Like within programming you specialize on Java and ignore C:

> Er spezialisiert sich *in* der Programmierung *auf* Java und ignoriert C.

In this case, the object related to the in-part needs to be dative.

Part 3) of Awful's answer - this is grammatically correct, but I never encountered this wording before.

Comment: thanks - but isn't "für" accusative as well?

Comment: yes, *für* would also go with accusative, but doesn't fit *spezialisieren* ... I slightly re-worded my answer; perhaps you mistook the part after the comma as "in case of" instead of a supplementary information.

Comment: Sollte der Beispielsatz nicht besser lauten: _Er spezialisiert sich auf Programmieren in Java und ignoriert C._ ?

Comment: @MartinPeters das wäre wiederum ein Spezialisieren *auf* ein einzelnes Fach (das "in" dahinter hat nichts mit dem Spezialisieren zu tun sondern kommt vom Programmieren in einer Sprache), in meinem Beispielsatz ging es um das Spezialisieren *in* einem Bereich (innerhalb des Programmierens).